# Tossing a triple of coins

Tags: probability

There is a red coin for which P(Heads) = 0.4, a green coin for which P(Heads) = 0.5 and a yellow coin for which P(Heads) = 0.6.

Let N be the number of heads in 300 tosses. Before each toss, I choose 1 of the 3 coins at random (each coin is equally likely to be selected).

What is the mean and variance of N?

I model N as follows: $$N = T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{300}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[T_i] = \frac{0.4 + 0.5 + 0.6}{3} = 0.5$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
Var(T_i) &=& \frac{1}{3}(0.4-\mathbb{E}[T_i])^2 + \frac{1}{3}(0.5-0.5)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(0.6-0.5)^2
\\ &=& \frac{(0.4-0.5)^2 + (0.5-0.5)^2 + (0.6-0.5)^2}{3}
\\ &=& \frac{0.02}{3}
\\ &=& \frac{1}{150}
\end{eqnarray}$$

By linearity of expectations and making use of the fact that all the Ts are iid,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}[N] &=& \mathbb{E}[T_1] + \mathbb{E}[T_2] + \cdots + \mathbb{E}[T_{300}]
\\ &=& 300 \cdot \mathbb{E}[T_1]
\\ &=& 150
\end{eqnarray}$$

Similarly, since the Ts are independent,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
Var(N) &=& Var(T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{300})
\\ &=& Var(T_1) + Var(T_2) + \cdots + Var(T_{300}) 
\\ &=& 300 \cdot Var(T_1)
\\ &=& 300 \cdot \frac{1}{150}
\\ &=& 2
\end{eqnarray}$$

I know that my calculation of the mean is correct. The variance is incorrect, but I haven't been able to figure out why.

Comment: Not getting how you are determining the variance. You should have something like $P(1)(1-0.5)^2 + P(0)(0-0.5)^2$, where $P(1)$ is the probability of having Heads. BTW, this is not any different from having just one single, fair, coin.

Comment: The variance Var(T1) above is the variance of the expectation, not the total variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in my calculation of the variance of T. I was able to get the right answer using a different approach.

By the law of total variance,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
Var(T_i) &=& \mathbb{E}[Var(T_i|coin)] + Var(\mathbb{E}[T_i|coin])
\\ &=& \mathbb{E}[P(1-P)] + Var(P)
\\ &=& \mathbb{E}[P] - \mathbb{E}[P^2] + \mathbb{E}[P^2] - (\mathbb{E}[P])^2
\\ &=& 0.5 - 0.5^2
\\ &=& 0.25
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
Var(N) &=& Var(T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{300})
\\ &=& 300 \cdot Var(T_i)
\\ &=& 300 \cdot 0.25
\\ &=& 75
\end{eqnarray}$$

Still don't understand why my first approach is wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you calculate $\mathbf{E}[T_i]$, you have actually used the law of total expectation and it is better to fully expand the expression like

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[T_i] &= \mathbf{E}[T_i \mid \mathrm{Red}] \cdot \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Red}) + \mathbf{E}[T_i \mid \mathrm{Green}] \cdot \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Green}) + \mathbf{E}[T_i \mid \mathrm{Yellow}] \cdot \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Yellow})\\ 
                         & = 0.4 \cdot \frac{1}{3} +  0.5 \cdot \frac{1}{3} +  0.6 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\\ 
                         & = 0.5
\end{align}

Then if you want to calculate $\mathrm{Var}(T_i)$ based on the definition of variance without using law of total variance, you could do following:

Notice $T_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable:

$$
T_i = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{with probability } p_1 \\
    0 & \text{with probability } p_0
\end{cases}
\quad \text{, where } p_1 + p_0 = 1
$$

Use law of total probability to calculate $p_0$ and $p_1$:

\begin{align}
p_1 &= \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Head} \mid \mathrm{Red}) \cdot \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Red}) + \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Head} \mid \mathrm{Green}) \cdot \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Green}) + \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Head} \mid \mathrm{Yellow}) \cdot \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{Yellow})
\\ & = 0.4 \cdot \frac{1}{3} +  0.5 \cdot \frac{1}{3} +  0.6 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\\ 
                         & = 0.5\\\\
p_0 &= 1-p_1\\& = 0.5
\end{align}

Use the definitions of the variance and expectation and the above results for $\mathbf{E}[T_i],\ p_0,\ p_1$:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(T_i) &= \mathbf{E}\Big[ \big( T_i - \mathbf{E}[T_i] \big)^2 \Big]\\ 
&= \big( 0 - \mathbf{E}[T_i] \big)^2 \cdot p_0 + \big( 1 - \mathbf{E}[T_i] \big)^2 \cdot p_1\\
&= ( 0 - 0.5)^2 \cdot 0.5+ ( 1 - 0.5)^2 \cdot 0.5\\
&= 0.25
\end{align}